# make an axis the default for an entire select

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to make an axis the default for an entire **select**.

After reading the above sentence myself i know its quite unclear so here's a longer explanation:

I'm finding a way to shorten this piece of code:

```
<xsl:variable name="v">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::name|self::history|self::area|self::title">qwerty</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
```

I'm talking about the part: **self::name|self::history|self::area|self::title** is there a way to shorten it to something like this: **self::(name|history|area|title)** ?

or anything else you guys could propose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach: whenever you see xsl:choose, ask whether you could use xsl:apply-templates instead. Why not:

```
<xsl:template match="name|history|area|title" mode="zingo">qwerty</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="zingo"/>

<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="zingo"/>
```

Comment: btw is there any reason you did self::* instead of just a single . or self::node() ?

Answer (score 0):

If the elements in question are part of a substitution group in the schema, then you can write `self::schema-element(e)` where e is the head of the substitution group. This is a very useful technique where you have a large family of interchangeable elements. In XSD 1.1 an element can belong to more than one substitution group, so you can even introduce substitution groups specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

```
select="self::name/following-sibling::*"
```

is possible...

Comment: It's possible, but its meaning is completely different to that of the original expression, so I've no idea why you are proposing it.